# int take just 2147483647, I want 9999999999

Tags: mysql, sql

In MYSQL database I took phone.no column and it's data type int. I take it from int(13) to int(30) but it's max value is 2147483647. 
I want max value to be 9999999999.

Comment: Then don't use an int. The max value is 2147483647.

Comment: Don't use a number type for phone numbers at all.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya:- You can use varchar for storing the numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is not recommended to use INT(or numeric datatype) for Phone Numbers.** The max value of int is **2147483647** so you cannot use more than that in it.

Also it would be better to use `varchar` to store phone number instead of int or bigint. You can use `varchar(15)` and certainly create index on that field. Also check [Telephone Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_number) on wikipedia.

**Reason** to use `varchar` instead of `Int` for phone numbers could be:-

1. You are not going to perform any `arithmetic operation(+,-,*,/)` on phone number fields so using varchar is a good option in my opinion.
2. Lets say you want to store the phone numbers in international format like +4412345667 or like (1234) 23456 then varchar would be better option.
3. If you want to compare two phone numbers like 00789768 and 0789768 then with the int datatype both will be equal but with varchar they are treated as two different phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

INT has a maximum value of 2147483647.  You will need to use BIGINT if you want a larger size, but for phone numbers, a VARCHAR is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql your change : "  int(13) to int(30) " 
only affect representation on selects and not on the size of the column when applied on on ints . (correct only for varchars)

What you needed as stated in the previous answers use the big int type.

In any case when discussing phone numbers ints are not really a good choice. When comparing ints 008877 and 00008877 are the same. So a better design choice will be to use a varchar with the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

We should always use **Varchar()** for storing Phone number instead of integer or bigint.